# How to determine the method used to launch a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I’ve created a single batch file that runs various apps on different servers when it is launched (different apps are run based upon computer name, day of week, time of day, etc.).  It isn’t actually a batch file but a link to a batch file (CMD actually) stored in a central network location for admins only.

Q:  How can I determine the method used to launch a batch file?  In other words, I’ve placed a shortcut to the batch file in the STARTUP group (folder) on the servers (so that it is run automatically when logging in to the server).  Then the batch file can do its thing and check the computer name, date/time, etc. and go from there).  But I’d also like to be able to run the batch file manually (either by clicking on a shortcut, launching it from the command prompt, from another batch file, from a group policy, etc.).  I just can’t figure out how to determine the method for launch a batch file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify the batch file?

If so, use a command line parameter to indicate it started from the Startup folder.

Near the top of the batch file, do a check like this:

```
IF "%1"=="STARTUP" THEN ...
```

Setup the Startup shortcut to call the batch file like this:

```
C:\folder\MyBatchFile.bat STARTUP
```

Comment: Yep, that will do it.  I can set up the batch file and test the command-link arg(s) to determine how it was launched.  Easiest method is usually the best.  Thanks!!